# Lambda expression to normal function

Tags: python

I am trying to understand lambda Python code. How to translate this in normal Python?

```
self.myarray = [j for j in line if j.type not in (obj.key1, obj.key2)]
```

Comment: it's not lambda, btw, it's a list comprehension. you can replicate with a normal `for` loop. are you familiar with those?

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: It is normal Python. I assume you mean with a `for` loop and not a list comprehension?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

That syntax represents a list comprehension and it does the same thing as below code:

```
self.myarray = []
for j in line:
    if j.type not in (obj.key1, obj.key2):
        self.myarray.append(j)
```